# IKImageView Display Video

Tags: objective-c, macos, uikit

I need to display video frames(NSImage) on `IKImageView` so that I can use the zoom, rotation functionality of `IKImageView` But the problem with below approach is that, the frames are not continues, sometimes blank screen appears between each frame.

Below is the relevent part of the code,

**ViewController.h**

```
@property (weak) IBOutlet IKImageView *IKImg;
```

**ViewController.m**

```
 NSDictionary* _imageProperties = NULL;
 CGImageRef source = [self CGImageCreateWithNSImage: image]; //NSImage to CGImageRef
 [_IKImg setImage: source  imageProperties: _imageProperties]; //each frame update here
```

So is it  possible to display continues frames using `IKImageView`?, my application work fine  using NSImageView .